# VPNGate Connections - OpenVPN Certificate Errors

Tags: ssl-certificate, openvpn, certificate, certificate-authority, ssl-certificate-errors

I've been trying to figure this out for the past few days but couldn't find anything specific to this case. It doesn't look complicated, but I also don't know how to fix it from my end.

VPNGate provides free VPN access of other good Samaritan users' Internet. I exclusively use OpenVPN to connect to these servers rather than their advertised software.

Here's a log when everything goes well, and I'm able to connect without issues:

```
Tue May 09 16:33:20 2017 OpenVPN 2.4.1 x86_64-w64-mingw32 [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [LZ4] [PKCS11] [AEAD] built on Mar 22 2017
Tue May 09 16:33:20 2017 Windows version 6.1 (Windows 7) 64bit
Tue May 09 16:33:20 2017 library versions: OpenSSL 1.0.2k  26 Jan 2017, LZO 2.09
Tue May 09 16:33:20 2017 MANAGEMENT: TCP Socket listening on [AF_INET]127.0.0.1:25341
Tue May 09 16:33:20 2017 Need hold release from management interface, waiting...
Tue May 09 16:33:21 2017 MANAGEMENT: Client connected from [AF_INET]127.0.0.1:25341
Tue May 09 16:33:21 2017 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'state on'
Tue May 09 16:33:21 2017 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'log all on'
Tue May 09 16:33:21 2017 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'echo all on'
Tue May 09 16:33:21 2017 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'hold off'
Tue May 09 16:33:21 2017 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'hold release'
Tue May 09 16:33:21 2017 WARNING: No server certificate verification method has been enabled.  See http://openvpn.net/howto.html#mitm for more info.
Tue May 09 16:33:21 2017 TCP/UDP: Preserving recently used remote address: [AF_INET]***:1426
Tue May 09 16:33:21 2017 Socket Buffers: R=[8192->8192] S=[8192->8192]
Tue May 09 16:33:21 2017 UDP link local: (not bound)
Tue May 09 16:33:21 2017 UDP link remote: [AF_INET]***:1426
Tue May 09 16:33:21 2017 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1494344001,WAIT,,,,,,
Tue May 09 16:33:21 2017 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1494344001,AUTH,,,,,,
Tue May 09 16:33:21 2017 TLS: Initial packet from [AF_INET]***:1426, sid=fcf3759f 64e4b082
Tue May 09 16:33:21 2017 VERIFY OK: depth=2, C=GB, ST=Greater Manchester, L=Salford, O=COMODO CA Limited, CN=COMODO RSA Certification Authority
Tue May 09 16:33:21 2017 VERIFY OK: depth=1, C=GB, ST=Greater Manchester, L=Salford, O=COMODO CA Limited, CN=COMODO RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA
Tue May 09 16:33:21 2017 VERIFY OK: depth=0, OU=Domain Control Validated, OU=PositiveSSL Wildcard, CN=*.opengw.net
Tue May 09 16:33:21 2017 Control Channel: TLSv1, cipher TLSv1/SSLv3 DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA, 2048 bit RSA
Tue May 09 16:33:21 2017 [*.opengw.net] Peer Connection Initiated with [AF_INET]***:1426
Tue May 09 16:33:23 2017 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1494344003,GET_CONFIG,,,,,,
Tue May 09 16:33:23 2017 SENT CONTROL [*.opengw.net]: 'PUSH_REQUEST' (status=1)
Tue May 09 16:33:23 2017 Key [AF_INET]***:1426 [0] not initialized (yet), dropping packet.
Tue May 09 16:33:23 2017 PUSH: Received control message: 'PUSH_REPLY,ping 3,ping-restart 10,ifconfig 10.211.1.5 10.211.1.6,dhcp-option DNS 10.211.254.254,dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8,route-gateway 10.211.1.6,redirect-gateway def1'
Tue May 09 16:33:23 2017 OPTIONS IMPORT: timers and/or timeouts modified
Tue May 09 16:33:23 2017 OPTIONS IMPORT: --ifconfig/up options modified
Tue May 09 16:33:23 2017 OPTIONS IMPORT: route options modified
Tue May 09 16:33:23 2017 OPTIONS IMPORT: route-related options modified
Tue May 09 16:33:23 2017 OPTIONS IMPORT: --ip-win32 and/or --dhcp-option options modified
Tue May 09 16:33:23 2017 Data Channel Encrypt: Cipher 'AES-128-CBC' initialized with 128 bit key
Tue May 09 16:33:23 2017 Data Channel Encrypt: Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication
Tue May 09 16:33:23 2017 Data Channel Decrypt: Cipher 'AES-128-CBC' initialized with 128 bit key
Tue May 09 16:33:23 2017 Data Channel Decrypt: Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication
Tue May 09 16:33:23 2017 interactive service msg_channel=312
Tue May 09 16:33:23 2017 ROUTE_GATEWAY 192.168.1.1/255.255.255.0 I=11 HWADDR=***
Tue May 09 16:33:23 2017 open_tun
```

Some servers have certificate errors. Here's a log:

```
Tue May 09 16:54:53 2017 OpenVPN 2.4.1 x86_64-w64-mingw32 [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [LZ4] [PKCS11] [AEAD] built on Mar 22 2017
Tue May 09 16:54:53 2017 Windows version 6.1 (Windows 7) 64bit
Tue May 09 16:54:53 2017 library versions: OpenSSL 1.0.2k  26 Jan 2017, LZO 2.09
Tue May 09 16:54:53 2017 MANAGEMENT: TCP Socket listening on [AF_INET]127.0.0.1:25342
Tue May 09 16:54:53 2017 Need hold release from management interface, waiting...
Tue May 09 16:54:53 2017 MANAGEMENT: Client connected from [AF_INET]127.0.0.1:25342
Tue May 09 16:54:53 2017 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'state on'
Tue May 09 16:54:53 2017 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'log all on'
Tue May 09 16:54:53 2017 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'echo all on'
Tue May 09 16:54:53 2017 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'hold off'
Tue May 09 16:54:53 2017 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'hold release'
Tue May 09 16:54:53 2017 WARNING: No server certificate verification method has been enabled.  See http://openvpn.net/howto.html#mitm for more info.
Tue May 09 16:54:53 2017 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1494345293,RESOLVE,,,,,,
Tue May 09 16:54:54 2017 TCP/UDP: Preserving recently used remote address: [AF_INET]***:1777
Tue May 09 16:54:54 2017 Socket Buffers: R=[8192->8192] S=[8192->8192]
Tue May 09 16:54:54 2017 UDP link local: (not bound)
Tue May 09 16:54:54 2017 UDP link remote: [AF_INET]***:1777
Tue May 09 16:54:54 2017 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1494345294,WAIT,,,,,,
Tue May 09 16:54:54 2017 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1494345294,AUTH,,,,,,
Tue May 09 16:54:54 2017 TLS: Initial packet from [AF_INET]***:1777, sid=2bd721a1 2b3738b9
Tue May 09 16:54:54 2017 VERIFY ERROR: depth=0, error=self signed certificate: CN=Kanes-pc, O=Kanes-pc, OU=Kanes-pc, C=US
Tue May 09 16:54:54 2017 OpenSSL: error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed
Tue May 09 16:54:54 2017 TLS_ERROR: BIO read tls_read_plaintext error
Tue May 09 16:54:54 2017 TLS Error: TLS object -> incoming plaintext read error
Tue May 09 16:54:54 2017 TLS Error: TLS handshake failed
Tue May 09 16:54:54 2017 SIGUSR1[soft,tls-error] received, process restarting
Tue May 09 16:54:54 2017 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1494345294,RECONNECTING,tls-error,,,,,
Tue May 09 16:54:54 2017 Restart pause, 5 second(s)
```

Both servers are UK based, so the certificate in Log#1 seems accurate. Log#2 is where things don't add up for me.

Two questions derive from this:

1. Is there a setting I can use within OpenVPN that would help me against MITM attacks when connecting to these servers? (I did read the info from the link provided but couldn't understand what setting is best to use and where to place it)
2. In regards to the certificate errors, any setting I can use within OpenVPN that would skip these errors and connect to the server?

Thank you.

Comment: If I understand you are using random unknown people's computers as part of your security solution. This pretty much means that security is already non-existent.

Comment: I appreciate the response. My inquiry is: How do I correctly configure OpenVPN on my end (what other settings must be added to the default configuration file) so that when I do connect to unknown *.ovpn servers (which could listen in), I can then mitigate such attacks? And also, does the error above in log#2 (which happens randomly), is there anything I can do on my end to never receive it again (or it's simply 100% dependant upon who created the *.ovpn file)

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using a public cert on the server and a self-signed cert on the client?  Almost every guide you will find for OpenVPN describes setting up an internal CA.

A connecting client needs to be signed by the CA specified by the `--ca` or `--capath` option on the server, at least by default.

Comment: Thanks for your response. My query is a lot more basic than I make it sound. I simply installed OpenVPN, downloaded some *.ovpn servers which are publicly available and tried to connect to them. Some work out of the box and some don't. The ones that don't seem to be improperly configured by who created them, although I feel I should still be able to connect to them with some tweaks on my end. I imagine I'm still missing the boat by quite a margin since my knowledge is limited in this field. Please elaborate if you can. Thank you.